# How can I avoid duplicating the message output code to the user?

Tags: angular

I have two modules in which, depending on the current state, a message is displayed to the player.
How can I avoid duplicating the message output code in the first and second modules?
Maybe I can do it somehow in the file app.component.html using a message template once? Or will you be able to come up with or know of another way to achieve this goal?
Thank you all in advance for your answers and help.

Maybe I can use the something similar to this json ?  But keep in mind that footer is a component.

```
MESSAGE_INIT: {
 title: 'Wait',
 body: {
  default: 'Please wait ...',
 },
 footer: WAITING_DOTS_COMPONENT
}

MESSAGE_DEPLOY: {
 title: 'Wait',
 body: {
  default: 'Please wait ...',
 },
 footer: WAITING_DOTS_COMPONENT
}

MESSAGE_END: {
 title: 'Game end',
 body: {
  looser: 'You are looser',
  winner: 'You are winner',
  default: 'Player is out',
 },
 footer: BUTTON_COMPONENT
}
```

message.component.html

```
<div class="message">
  <div class="message__content">
    <div class="message__title">
      <ng-content select="[title]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="message__body">
      <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="message__footer">
      <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

first.module.html

```
<div class="first">
 ...something

 <app-message *ngIf="state === 'INIT'">
  <ng-container title>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container body>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container footer>...</ng-container>
 </app-message>

 <app-message *ngIf="state === 'DEPLOY'">
  <ng-container title>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container body>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container footer>...</ng-container>
 </app-message>

 <app-message *ngIf="state === 'END'">
  <ng-container title>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container body>...</ng-container>
  <ng-container footer>...</ng-container>
 </app-message>
<div>
```

second.module.html

```
<div class="second">
  ...something

  <app-message *ngIf="END">
    <ng-container title>...</ng-container>
    <ng-container body>...</ng-container>
    <ng-container footer>...</ng-container>
  </app-message>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your `app-message` component or add another level of abstraction on top of it as to encapsulate the repeating logic.

More concreately, you could have a component that takes your `state` as an input and displays the appropriate message. You could have default messages for the different possible states of your app, and could also expose an input taking a map of states to messages, allowing the user of the component to customize the behavior. Now, that "message" does not have to be a string, it could be any object like the JSONs you have. Whatever the component needs to consume.

Does that answer your question?